# Angular time formatting incorrectly

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the following JSON back from a service:

```
{
    "DailyEventCaseID": 1,
    "LocID": "LA ",
    "CourtRoom": "9",
    "CaseID": 3,
    "EventDate": "2015-09-14T00:00:00",
    "SortTime": "08:30",
    "SeqNumber": 1,
    "StatusID": null,
    "Case": {
      "CaseID": 3,
      "CaseNumber": "BP118652",
      "DivisionCode": "PR",
      "District": "LA ",
      "CaseTitle": "KRAUS, MARGARITH - TRUST DTD 07/07/98"
    },
    "Status": null,
    "Events": [
      {
        "EventID": 9,
        "DailyEventCaseID": 1,
        "EntityNumber": "0020",
        "EventName": "INSTRUCTIONS",
        "DailyEventCase": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want the field SortTime to display as 8:30 am so I have it in my view as:

```
{{case.SortTime | date: 'h:mm a'}}
```

It still just shows as 8:30 and not 8:30 am.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the SortTime value(from the JSON) has no information about whether it is am or pm, so how would angular's date filter be able to figure that out?

Comment: SortTime isn't a valid date.

Comment: The filter is actually not able to parse your time at all and is passing it through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `case.SortTime` is not a date object. It is just a string. So date filter is not applied.

**Method 1:**
Assuming that you need only time regardless date, I suggest you this method. But it is not a good practice.
In your controller, you can overwrite `case.SortTime` as

```
timeParams = $scope.case.SortTime.split(':')
$scope.case.SortTime = new Date(0,0,0,timeParams[0],timeParams[1])
```

Now `{{case.SortTime | date: 'h:mm a'}}` will give you date with `AM/PM`.
See http://jsfiddle.net/radik305411/dys6atmj/ for help.

**Method 2:** Create a custom filter.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('timeFilter', function () {
  return function (sortTime) {
    var timeParams = sortTime.split(":");
    timeParams[2] = "AM"
    if(timeParams[0] >= 12){
       timeParams[0] -= 12;
       timeParams[2] = "PM"
    }
    return timeParams[0]+':'+timeParams[1]+' '+timeParams[2]
  };
});
```

Now `{{case.SortTime | timeFilter }}` will give the result you need.

Comment: Thanks...based upon your answer we are changing the service to return a date/time object